# Having trouble to display html output in data bricks python

Tags: python, classification, databricks, azure-databricks, lime

There are similar question, but nothing solve my problem. One thing I think that the last line of my code doesn't work in data bricks (where I am working). I am displaying part of the code which you actually can't reproduce, but it's probably small issue that might be solved without reproducing code. But if it's needed, I will update that.

Another thing I got that I can probably use

```
displayHTML("""<p>https://www.medium.com" </p>""")
```

But I couldn't figure out how to get the the link. The part of the code is below (I fit a classification model) and want to use lime package to interpret.

```
!pip install lime
import lime
from lime import lime_tabular

explainer = lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(
    training_data=np.array(X_train),
    feature_names=X_train.columns,
    class_names=['Fail', 'No_Fail'],
    mode='classification'
)
exp = explainer.explain_instance(
    data_row=X_test.iloc[1], 
    predict_fn=lgbm_class.predict_proba
)
exp.show_in_notebook(show_table=True)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Call to `explainer.explain_instance` returns an instance of the `Explainer` class, and this instance has the [`as_html` function](https://lime-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lime.html#lime.explanation.Explanation.as_html), so following theoretically should work:

```py
exp = explainer.explain_instance(
    data_row=X_test.iloc[1], 
    predict_fn=lgbm_class.predict_proba
)
displayHTML(exp.as_html())
```